# Script not running on window.resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize

The following is being used to equalize height of several divs. Runs fine on pageload, not working on window resize.

Thoughts?

```
function equalHeight(group) {
tallest = 0;
group.each(function() {
   thisHeight = $(this).height();
   if(thisHeight > tallest) {
      tallest = thisHeight;
   }
});
group.height(tallest);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 equalHeight($(".equal"));
});
$(window).resize(function() {
 equalHeight($(".equal"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was because on resize, the height was already set from the previous running of the function on load. I've added `$(this).height('auto');` to the `each` function, and also changed `$(document).ready(function(){})` to `$(window).load(function(){});` See Below:

```
function equalHeight(group) {
   tallest = 0;
   group.each(function() {
      $(this).height('auto');
      thisHeight = $(this).height();
      if(thisHeight > tallest) {
         tallest = thisHeight;
      }
   });
   group.height(tallest);
}
$(window).load(function() {
   equalHeight($(".equal"));
});
$(window).resize(function() {
   equalHeight($(".equal"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function equalHeight(group) {
tallest = 0;
group.each(function() {
   thisHeight = $(this).height();
   if(thisHeight > tallest) {
      tallest = thisHeight;
   }
}));
group.height(tallest);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 equalHeight($(".equal"));
});
$(window).resize(function() {
 equalHeight($(".equal"));
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Console says your syntax is incorrect. I moved the second close round bracket to the end of the function, still doesn't work